# Closing Modal Page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, modal-dialog

I am opening new ContentPage like this:

```
MediaPage galleryPage = new MediaPage();
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(galleryPage);
```

Now, when done with the task in that page, I would like to close it and come back to last page where I was before opening ModalPage.

I tried like this:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked how many pages are there in the stack?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are executing it from the main thread? Try this:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
});
```

Comment: I realized I had incorrect Command binding. it works how, however I have another problem tthat I will be making new thread about